# Ruby on rails : some array information show up automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a list on the webpage generated from database. 
It first shows what I want : `Beaf` .
However after this information, some others information of the array show up automatically:

```
<Ingredient id: 1, name: "Beaf", groupid: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

How can I remove it? Thank you very much!

Comment: You should post your view code. It's likely you've got `<%= @my_collection.each { ... } %>` somewhere in your code.

Comment: Yes I use the <%= @ingredients.each do |i| %> to get the list. Sorry I have trouble with the laptop so I cannot upload image right now.

Comment: so it is impossible `<%= @ingredients.each do |i| %>` like this `<% @ingredients.each do |i| %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Instead of using
<%= @ingredients.each do |i| %>

# use
<% @ingredients.each do |i| %>
```

The `=` will output all ingredients, whereas your output should only occur in the loop itself